# How to create an igraph object from an adjacency matrix

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-matrix, sna

I wanted to create an `igraph` dataset in R to analyze the social networks I coded in the original adjacency matrix. Below you'll find the code I used:

```
returnees_data <- read.table(
  "Returnees_Test1.csv", 
  sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, row.names=1)

returnees_i <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(
  returnees_data,
  mode = c("undirected"),
  weighted = TRUE,
  diag = FALSE)
```

When I ran the second command, R responded

> Error in mde(x) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'.

I tried the `unlist()` command, but that didn't worked and I couldn't find another suitable solution...Now I don't know if the problem is in my code or in my data, since the following commands worked:

```
gplot(returnees_data,
      gmode="graph",       # type of network: undirected
      mode="kamadakawai",  # how the nodes are positioned
      vertex.cex=.8,       # the size of the node shapes
      usearrows=FALSE,     #no arrows
      displaylabels=TRUE,  # to add the node labels
      label.pos=1,        # labels below the node shapes
      label.cex=.5,        # size of the node labels
      edge.col="grey70")   # color of ties 70% white

sna::degree(returnees_data, gmode="graph")
```

Comment: Compare `d = as.data.frame(diag(3)); graph_from_adjacency_matrix(d,mode = c("undirected"), weighted = TRUE)` with `graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(d),mode = c("undirected"), weighted = TRUE)`

Comment: I tried it and I got the same error.

Comment: What did you try? From your code above i'd think that `m = as.matrix(returnees_data)` then `g = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE)` should work ... or at least not give the same error. If this is not working then you need to have a look at `returnees_data` -- is it read in correctly? You can check with `str(returnees_data)`.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without knowing the contents of `returnees_data`. So show us the result of `dput(returnees_data[,1:10])`, which are the first 10 lines of the adjacency matrix.

Comment: Ah, now it worked....don't know what I did wrong the first time. Thanks a lot for your help!